# Phone manufacturer prevents installation of apps signed by third paries, does anyone know a way around this?

Tags: adb, apk

I'm trying to put apps on an LG Exalt VN220, which is a flip phone that runs on a limited version of android. Whenever I try to install an apk using adb I get the following message: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES. From a quick Google search I learned that this usually occurs when you try updating an app with an update that has a different certificate. This can not be the case because these apps were never installed on the phone before. When I pulled stock apps from the phone and tried to install them I got: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION. However when I install apps by LG that did not come on the phone they successfully install. Does anybody know if there is a way to get around this?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  This is a rather old phone.  ❧  When was the last firmware update released?  Maybe it has some security vulnerabilities.  Can you somehow [root the phone](https://www.google.com/search?q=root+LG+Exalt)?  ❧  Why do you want to install apps on a flip phone?  You could buy a different low-end phone (maybe a refurbished Moto E6 or something) for not much money.

Comment: How many apps and which specific apps have you tested?

Comment: I've tried WhatsApp, eReader Prestigio, Waze and a ton of other apps. It seems to be all apps that are not signed by LG.

Comment: Reading responses from the folks on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/rooting-lg-exalt-lte-verizon-lg-vn220-t3668054), they haven't been successful either, and looks like this is a very locked-down phone. I'm afraid there's no solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it works with LG exactly because I don't own an LG phone. But I had similar issue with my mi phone.

Before you can install any apps using adb you need to enable developer setting allow usb debugging, and allow install via usb. LG might have some other flags too

In older version of android there was a switch - "allow install from unknown sources". Please look for these settings and do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

This phone is locked down by the manufacturer and will not allow 3rd party apps. Apps compiled by LG will usually pass though, if they meet specific criteria.

Because it is a flip phone running in a dumbed down android environment, the system state is fragile and warrants extra protection.

Also, as of now, there is no known root method for this device, and it is unlikely that the device will generate enough interest in the dev community to produce one. ([See Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/rooting-lg-exalt-lte-verizon-lg-vn220-t3668054).)

4G Flip phones from other manufactures are more susceptible to hacks and workarounds than the LG Exalt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the manifest.xml to `com.android.cts.originalpackagename`, if you only edit the xml, and not a recompile of the app, it will get past the signature check. as esaphire mentioned, [apps4flip](https://apps4flip.com) and [kosherappsforflip](http://kosherappsforflip.wixsite.com/) have a bunch of already edited apps.